# Google Mobile Ads blocked on certain bundle ID (iOS Apps)

Tags: ios, admob, google-ad-manager

i have a very old problem for my app. My app cannot show an ads while using bundle ID for production. But when i change it to anything for example my prod bundle id is my.apps.prod, then i changed it using my.apps.test, it shows the ads. I only test this using ad unit testing, so it should be working for both bundle id.

I have asked the Google Ad Manager in some of the discussion forum, but seems not getting any proper solution for this. They just gave some bot answer maybe? Because i've seen the same answer many times already. I'm convince that my bundle id is blocked or something, but yeah no proper solution given in the discussion. We've tried to solve that with the bot answer too.

Anyone ever faced this problem? It's been almost a year, and nothing is working, and we do not know where to ask anymore. There's also no real person customer service in Google Ad Manager. Such a pain solving this problem.

Comment: Can you share how you are loading an ad? Also, what do you see in the logs when loading an ad (if anything)?

Comment: I load the ads as the docs in the google ad manager website. It worked just fine when i change the bundle id to testing bundle id or whatever except the prod bundle id. The error is this: Request Error: No ad to show. As an additional information, using Google IMA iOS SDK also not working when i used the prod bundle but worked just fine using testing bundle. Discussing in the ima or admob forum seems to solve nothing @tomerpacific